# Navigation in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Learning Android development, and has two questions about navigation. My application target recent android platform (API level Honey Comb) on tablet only.

1. When to use Tabbed navigation in ActionBar

   The tabbed navigation switch between fragments and limited within current activity. I saw Honeycomb Gallery example where it is used to switch between Ballons, etc. Still, not sure when it best to use tabbed navigation or use separate activity.
2. What is the most common way to navigate between activities.
   So far the examples I saw, I have not seen one with a menu which allows navigation between activities. What is the common way to do this. Especially post HoneyComb, the easiest (if possible through xml markup) way to achieve navigation between activities.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was approaching this based on my web application dev experience.

Android doc explain in quite detail about patterns to use for navigation. Especially,

http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/index.html
http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html